# How to install different version of program?

Tags: software-installation

What is the usual way of installing a different version of a program on Ubuntu?

Comment: Too broad! Which program?

Comment: `sudo apt install package=version` for example `sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64=2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.2`

Comment: I agree with pomsky ... i could grab add a ppa, grab source & compile; add repo's, even install a deb (directly or via repo add) from later versions & deal with deps & issues as consequence which is none-minimal for some apps & horrific for others (though largely predictable).   There is no *usual* way as the best approach varies case-to-case, and upon your technical level too.  Your knowledge will grow as you use Ubuntu and then you'll try things, and discover the various ways (and their drawbacks) to approaches.

Comment: @darkangel I believe your question is different from the marked duplicated.  I see how it could be interpreted as the same.  Your question appears to be looking for a method to install an additional version (**not changing the installed version**), the other appears to be about a different version  (**changing the installed version**).  I may be wrong with your intentions.  If you would [add details](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1024804/edit) of your issue (as asked for by @pomsky) it would be helpful, and I may vote to reopen your question accordingly.  I can't edit and change your intentions.

Answer (score 2):

Some programs allow more than one version to be installed at the same time.  Some examples includes `php`, `python`, `java`, etc.

From the Software Center or the commandline, specify the version you want to install.

To install the default version of the program (openjdk) in this case run:

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk
```

You can use `apt` search option to check the available version from your installed repository with this command (among other variations).  I'm including the command and the output in this example:

```
$ apt search openjdk | egrep ^open.*jdk/

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

openjdk-6-jdk/lucid 6b18-1.8-0ubuntu1 amd64
openjdk-8-jdk/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8u162-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 amd64 [installed]
openjdk-9-jdk/xenial,now 9~b114-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
ljames@ubunzeus:~$
```

**To install openjdk version 8, I would run this command (as an example):**

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

In short, run the install as normal and include the version of the application as part of the install command.

Comment: @N0rbert That is the output of the command.  Did you test the command on your computer?  The output is showing the versions of **openjdk-6-jdk** that is installed on my computer.  I don't recall ever specifying an **openjdk version 6** for install, but it has been a number of years since I performed a clean OS installation.  In this case, the output may help to demonstrate how **apt** automatically maintains the different dependency packages when facilitating multiple version installs.

Comment: By the way, I have never performed the (apparent) complicated commandlines of the duplicated answer.  I'm sure that's because I have never had desire, or need to change to a different version.  I always use the current default version unless there's need to install an additional version for a specific task.  This is when both versions are in the repository being maintained without conflicting depencies that would be require addressing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76023/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-n0rbert).

Comment: I accepted your arguments, so we can remove the comments of conversation.